# SED wildcard selects too large range

Tags: sed, geektool

Working with Sed on Mac osx 10.6.8 creating a .command file with Text Editor which will be executed in Geektool. I have a string  MYSTRING and try to remove the link-tags from it. But when using the wildcard Sed seems to select a too long range.

```
MYSTRING="<link>part_1</link>This part must remain.<link>part_x</link> Like this part."
echo $MYSTRING |
sed s/"<link>".*"<\/link>"//g
```

I had expected this result:

```
This part must remain. Like this part.
```

But the actual result is:

```
 Like this part.
```

It seems that Sed takes the first link as the from-value and the last /link as the to-value, causing everything in between to be deleted. How do I make Sed understand it should take the first /link after link rather than taking the last?

Comment: You should always double-quote your variable interpolations; `echo "$MYSTRING"`

Answer (score 1):

Because `.*` is greedy. Try:

```
sed 's@<link>[^<]*</link>@@g'
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the regex repetition operator `*` is to match the longest, leftmost possible match. Unfortunately, `sed` does not support stingy matching, but Perl does:

```
perl -pe 's%<link>.*?</link>%%g'
```

or maybe you can formulate a regex where greedy matching is unproblematic;

```
sed 's%<link>[^<>]*</link>%%g'
```